# asp.net core web api - same url with different query parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a controller class as below:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ItemController : Controller
{
    //GET api/item?employId=1009
    [HttpGet]
    public List<ItemViewModel> GetByEmployId([FromQuery]long employId) {
            return new List<ItemViewModel>() {
                new ItemViewModel(),
                new ItemViewModel(),
                new ItemViewModel()
            };
    }

    // GET api/item?managerId=1009
    [HttpGet]
    public List<ItemViewModel> GetByManagerId([FromQuery]long managerId) {
        return new List<ItemViewModel>();
    }
}
```

For the first URL (http://localhost/api/item?employId=1), the web api can return results. But for the second URL (http://localhost/api/item?managerId=2), the web api return error with HTTP code 500. Can someone help on why this happens? Thanks.

For some reason, I can't debug with the web api project.

Comment: The routes only match the path, not the query. You should apply the RESTful and represent your resources via urls. i.e. `http://localhost/api/manager/2/item`

Comment: I agree with Tseng. But that said, your code should work. HTTP 500 suggests an error. Were you running the debugger when that happened? Did you see an exception? Also, the error page should tell you an error message.

Comment: @GabrielLuci is correct. The code you've posted here will not generate a 500, so the only assumption is that what you've posted is not an accurate representation of the code you're actually running. Perhaps you redacted too much. Regardless, please create a complete, minimal and reproduceable sample. Currently, you do not have that.

Comment: Hi @Tseng , thanks for the advice. For this moment, we can't change the URL to RESTful style because there is a deadline in near future.

Comment: Hi @GabrielLuci, the web api is actually hosted in Azure Service Fabric (although it's hosted in local cluster), for some reason, everytime I start the service fabric project (which refers the web api project) with 'Start Debugging' in Visual Studio, VS throws out an error message "A fatal error has occurred....". We know this error is caused by the projects upgraded to .NET Core 2.0 but don't know why. That's why I mentioned I can't debug it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes, you are right. I should create a demo project test it. This morning I create one and it shows 'AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. '. Looks I can't create 2 web apis with different query parameters, ie. api/item?query1=123 and api/item?query2=456. This morning I just realize that the web api I want is something like api/item?query1=123&query2=456 so that I just need one method in controller class.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: ambiguous routes create an exception on startup/during request too IIRC and both action methods have the same path segment, since the WebAPI styled Uris are used and not MVC styled ones (with `[action]` parameter)

Comment: And @yyou: Sure you can try to delay it to a  later point, but changing public API after release is a pain in the ass, because its a breaking change and will break all consumers of that API. You better get that sorted out before you release your product. Changing routes is pretty easy thing to do, just work through all of your controllers and change it. The clients need to adjust their urls, but if you use Swagger or any other generator you'll be able to automatically generate rest clients from the swagger specs

Answer (score 1):

A bit outdated but just if someone has the same problem can find the response here. To achieve this you just have to add your queries params as function params. Using the same example.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ItemController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public List<ItemViewModel> Get([FromQuery]long employId, [FromQuery] long managerId) {
            if(employId != null){
                    return new List<ItemViewModel>() {
                new ItemViewModel(),
                new ItemViewModel(),
                new ItemViewModel()
              };
             }
            if(managerId != null){

               return new List<ItemViewModel>();
           }

          return new List();

    }


}
```

Comment: Doing it like that you can get some benefits and one of them is that you can establish some priority to the query params.