# Action method overrides for HTTPPost .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have two Post method one is taking single object and one is taking list of object, how to do this overriding in .net core?

```
// taking list of object
[HttpPost("matchdob")]
public MatchDOBResponse MatchDOB(List<DOBMatchRequest> requestModel)
{
  //
}
// taking single object
[HttpPost("matchdob")]
public MatchDOBResponse MatchDOB(DOBMatchRequest requestModel)
{
  //
}
```

its not working, how to solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to the stack overflow!! First of all whatever example you provide its is know as **`Method Overloading`**.

Comment: you could simply have a list itself and send one `DOBMatchRequest`  in it instead a over ride, I don't think that would be possible

Comment: yes if it would be a array list then I know it, but I am asking about, is it possible by overriding?

Comment: No with overload, because you can't expose 2 APIs with same URL. But you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522097/asp-net-core-web-api-same-url-with-different-query-parameter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436866/can-you-overload-controller-methods-in-asp-net-mvc have look into it

Comment: You cannot do action overloads. The way routing works in ASP.NET Core is different than how it did in ASP.NET Web Api. You need to choose different names for your handlers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the multiple action with the same template name. Each action should have a unique route name.

Try use different name, like this:

```
// taking list of object
[HttpPost("matchdmultipleob")]
public MatchDOBResponse MatchDOB(List<DOBMatchRequest> requestModel)
{
  //
}
// taking single object
[HttpPost("matchdsingleob")]
public MatchDOBResponse MatchDOB(DOBMatchRequest requestModel)
{
  //
}
```

Or you can use one action method and receive a list of object, then check the count:

```
[HttpPost("matchdob")]
public MatchDOBResponse MatchDOB(List<DOBMatchRequest> requestModel)
{
    if (requestModel.Count == 1)
    {
        //upload single object
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        //upload list of object
    }

    //
    return new MatchDOBResponse() { Status = "200", Message = "Success" };
}
```

Comment: I know both of this things, anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible to implement what you are asking. It is necessary to use the route constraints.

For example, the following two action method will be called with the same action name `Method` depend on the `data` parameter type: the first when `data` is `int`, and the second when the `data` parameter is `bool`.

```cs
[HttpPost, Route("{data:int}")]        
public IActionResult Method(int data)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Method1", data);
}

[HttpPost, Route("{data:bool}")]        
public IActionResult Method(bool data)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Method2", data);
}
```

In your case the ***Custom route constraints*** should be implemented to use this feature: one class to support `DOBMatchRequest` type, and the second class for `List<DOBMatchRequest>` type.

For more information see:

[Route constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#route-constraints)

[Custom route constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-route-constraints)

<sub>Note: Yes... this is more likely *`overloading`*, not *`overriding`*.</sub>